# Question about linear transformation and kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices with entries in $\Bbb{R}$, and define a map
\begin{align*}
T: M&\to\Bbb{R}^2\\
A&\mapsto Aw,
\end{align*}
where $w=\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}$.

a)Is $T$ a linear transformation?

b)Find a basis for $\ker T$

I know how to do a, but for b, I have no clue how to do it. Please help.

Comment: please check that the edit is what you intended

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can show that for every $A,B\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$; $T(aA+B)=aT(A)+T(B)$ by taking two $2\times 2$ matrices $A,B$. Note that if $A\in ker(T)$, so $T(A)=0$ and then we have $$a+3b=0,  c+3d=0$$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  c&d 
\end{pmatrix}$. Solve the system above to find a proper vector.

Comment: I am confuced, i try to do it, and i got the basis is (-3,1)

Comment: You want to find the kernel of the transformation, so you take an arbitrary matrix whose entries Babak denoted by $a,b,c$ and $d$ and find all such quantities that transform the vector $(1,3)^T$ to zero. Solving the associated linear system yields a two-parameter family of solutions, for example if you let $b=t$ and $d=s$ then your solution space is of the form $a=-3t,b=t,c=-3s,d=s$, meaning that plugging in any value for $s$ and $t$ will yield a solution of your system.

Comment: The "vectors" in your space are 2x2 matrices, so how could $(-3,1)$ be a basis?

Comment: So the basis should be (-3,1
                        -3,1)?

Comment: @PrinceZhao: As dezign noted you have a solution space generated as pointed above, so the matrix you asked is one of them. Think of another matrices which the linear combination of them could build the whole space.

Comment: Think about $v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
  -3 & 1 \\
  0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}, v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  -3&1 
\end{pmatrix}$.